# What are these extra black wires connected to my doorbell chime?

Tags: electrical, doorbell

I attempted to install a new SimpliSafe video doorbell, and after everything was connected I found that the doorbell chime inside produced a disturbing humming sound. I contacted SimpliSafe, who sent me their Doorbell Chime Connector device.  This basically acts as an electrical bypass and has helped other customers who experienced doorbell buzzing after installation.

For me, however, after installing the Chime Connector, the doorbell chime still hums / buzzes. It only stops when I take the doorbell off of its mount outside the house, which tells me that the humming is resulting from the unit drawing power.

I believe part of the problem could be that the electrical wiring near my doorbell chime doesn't completely match the diagram shown in the Doorbell Chime Connector instructions. The instructions only refer to wires coming out of the wall for the Front and Trans wires, both of which we are told to connect to the Chime Connector. However, the wires near my doorbell chime also include 2 old-looking black wires with scraggly copper fibers coming out of them. Prior to installing the SimpliSafe Doorbell Chime Connector, these old black wires were also wired to the Front and Trans terminals just like the red and yellow wires that are normally there.

Does anyone have any experience with this? What are these old black wires? What should I do with them?

Here are 2 pictures of the doorbell chime and wires along with the SimpliSafe Doorbell Chime Connector, followed by a short video of the doorbell chime making the humming sound:

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

- Video:
  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Sa8j9McGjoH4p9N_geZfV-cloPzOPLia

Thanks!
- Jason

Comment: Are you sure the stranded wires are not touching the other terminals? It looks like you have both a front and rear setup, but I question if it is wired correctly , I would guess the black wires are the supply and 1 should be on the center screw, the other should be connected to the switches, then the switches connected to the front and rear terminals.